# Add query string to a Google Webapp URL

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, template-engine

```
//htmlFileName: String
function createTemplate(htmlFileName) {
    let {protocol,stdName} = getProtocolData()
    let params = protocol   // protocol: String, exemple 987654321
    let url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/xxxxx.xxx.xx/s/beenchangedforsecurity/exec'

    url += '?' + 'p' + '=' + params

  /** **MY GOAL: url**   *
  * https://script.google.com/a/macros/xxxxx.xxx.xx/s/beenchangedforsecurity/exec?p=987654321
  */

 let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(htmlFileName)  
 html.protocol = protocol
 html.stdName  = stdName
 html.url      = url
 Logger.log(html.protocol)
 Logger.log(html.stdName)
 Logger.log(html.url)

 return html.evaluate().getBlob().getDataAsString() }
```

> ERROR:
> Exception: Malformed HTML content: `https://script.google.com/a/macros/xxxxx.xxx.xx/s/beenchangedforsecurity/exec?p=000002036`

Comment: I don't think the error is telling you there is something wrong with the url.  I think it's telling you there is something wrong with the html.  I think the querystring is okay

Comment: Please add a [mvce] (include the .html file and all the required details to reproduce the problem)

Comment: @Cooper, Thanks for your reply. I reviewed the HTML and corrected 2 open tags and now it is working.  But I'm experincing new issue: the parameters (query string) is not showed when URL is opned and this is crucial do get the protocol number and fill the protocol field in the form, autromatticaly

Please take a look at:
https://jsfiddle.net/jcmafra/g70e8a1L/39/

Comment: I would not put single quotes around the parameter

Comment: @Cooper, with or without single quotes in param value it did not work, please take a look again. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I reviwed my HTML code and made this change:

original:

```
<p>
  <form id="btn1" action= " https://script.google.com/macros/s/blablabla/exec/?p='1234567890' " >
    <button typy="submit" id="uploadButton1"> Click here to send docs (param value with singlew quotes) </button>
  </form>
<p>
```

new code:

```
 <p> 
  <a id="clickhere" class="button" href= " <?!= url ?> " >
      Clique aqui para enviar os documentos
  </a>
</p>
```

I understood that  in  can not send query string by GET method. @Cooper, thank you again for your tip.